# Android multiple request for real time data

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit2 in my application. My problem is that I have a group of persons in my list and all these persons are to be continuously monitored.
  Monitoring in the sense that I need to make a retrofit call for each person ,to obtain the real time data of that person.
  For example,

```
 Consider person 1 :
    My initial request call will be with the following data.
    {
     "patientId" : "qwerty1",
     "time": ""
    }
    Response is:
   {
     "data" : [],
     "updated_time" : "16519644"
   }

   Next request for person 1 :
    {
      "patientId" : "qwerty1",
      "time": "16519644"
    }
```

and this repeats. Server side coding is in such a way that only a set of 20 data are provided as response for our request. So to obtain continuous data set we need to make repeated call. I need to do this process for "n" number of persons in real time. Also I need to update UI when there is a response. I am really confused with the concept of sending retrofit request in a loop. Please suggest a way.

Comment: Why dont you make just one call for all persons ?

Comment: Your backend is coded that way or its restriction by hosting ?

Comment: @JozefDochan Backend is coded in that way

Comment: then maybe try to write it better ?

Comment: They have done it to prevent the system from delay